# SQL Parameters Formatting Issue

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, parameters

In my C# MVC4 application, I have the following code:

```
 string[] parameters = new string[items.Count];
            SqlCommand SecondQuery = new SqlCommand();
            for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
            {
                parameters[i] = string.Format(items[i].Id);
                SecondQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameters[i], items[i]);
            }
            SecondQuery.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * from S_analysis WHERE heat_no IN ({0})", string.Join(", ", parameters));
            SecondQuery.Connection = new SqlConnection(strSQLconnection);
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strSQLconnection))
            {
                SecondQuery.CommandTimeout = 50000;
                conn.Open();
                SecondQuery.Connection = new SqlConnection(strSQLconnection);
                SecondQuery.Connection.Open();

                using (var reader7 = SecondQuery.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    int fieldCount = reader7.FieldCount;

                    while (reader7.Read())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            finalresults.Add(reader7[i].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

My application crashes on the line: `using (var reader7 = SecondQuery.ExecuteReader())` with this error:`No mapping exists from object type <>f__AnonymousType42[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] to a known managed provider native type.`

Im assuming this is because when I view my SecondQuery.CommandText my query looks like:`SecondQuery.CommandText = "SELECT * from S_analysis WHERE heat_no IN (B5P5649, B5P5647, B5P5656, A5P0761, A5P0762)"`  I believe each parameter within the IN portion of the code should have the single quote symbol on each side.  How can I modify my code to add this or is this what is causing my error?

Comment: 3 Sqlconnections and one execute? something not right about that...

Comment: You really should consider better naming conventions for your variables.  `SecondQuery`, for example, would look much better as, `secondQuery`.  Not to mention (although I am mentioning it), `finalResults` instead of `finalresults`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right in that string values need to be quoted for SQL Server.

```
string.Join(", ", parameters)
```

There are many options, but this would work ***if this were the only problem***

```
"'"+string.Join(",", parameters).Replace(",", "','")+"'"
```

However, the bugs in your code are more extensive. You were attempting to parameterize each item - this doesn't work since nowhere in the CommandText are you specifying the placeholders. All you have is the static `IN` list.  You also have far more SqlConnection instances than required.

```
        string[] parameters = new string[items.Count];
        SqlCommand SecondQuery = new SqlCommand();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            parameters[i] = "'" + string.Format(items[i].Id) + "'";
            //SecondQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameters[i], items[i]);
        }
        SecondQuery.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * from S_analysis WHERE heat_no IN ({0})", string.Join(",", parameters));
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strSQLconnection))
        {
            SecondQuery.CommandTimeout = 50000;
            conn.Open();
            SecondQuery.Connection = conn;

            using (var reader7 = SecondQuery.ExecuteReader())
            {
                int fieldCount = reader7.FieldCount;

                while (reader7.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        finalresults.Add(reader7[i].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  Im confused about your removal of the code where I am placing values from items into the string array.  Each item in items has two values (an id and a date).  I only want to use the ids as parameters.

Comment: My mistake. I thought it was a straight copy of string[] -> string[]. I have also elected to quote the strings in the loop rather than .replace after .join in my revision.

Comment: Wish I could upvote your answer multiple times.  These changes were invaluable.